# Close Vote Review Audit dispute

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Audit link - https://www.stackoverflow.com/review/close/19460621

I got the above audit in the CV review queue and I failed the test. For some reason, the audit added the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag to the question (I have filtered the queue with `too-broad` & `tagged python` questions), so, naturally, I thought OP wanted code for an answer while having presented nothing (in terms of their efforts), so I closed it as too-broad, which apparently wasn't the right choice according to the audit. Even considering just the [algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) tag on the question, I'd have voted it for closing (or perhaps skipped), so, IMO, this audit is wrong, or at the very least, disputable.

Kindly consider removing this question from the audit queue.

Comment: The "for some reason" is a part of audits, and more often than not will _help_ you spot an audit. An android post with [python] is somewhat suspicious, usually. Next to [algorithms] it's trickier.